# Date insert to sqlite db using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite

For my learning purpose I have created a simple application using `Sqlite DB` along with `Hibernate` and `Struts 2`. In that I am trying to insert a row to a table - User(id,mydate). The insertion is happening without any error, but when I retrieve the data back from the db and try to display it on the screen, it displays incorrect data. I don't know what wrong I am doing. The value of the date column is retrieved as `1/1/70 5:30:02 AM.007`. Below are the code that might be related to this.

**User.java**

```
public class User implements Serializable {
     private Integer id;
     private Date mydate;
     //getters and setters
}
```

**user.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.User" table="user">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="id" />
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="mydate" type="java.util.Date">
        <column name="mydate" />
    </property>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Insert Statement**

```
insert into user(id,mydate) values (2,DATE('2013-04-03'));
```

**Query Method**

```
@Override
public User queryByUserId(Integer id) {
   return getHibernateTemplate().get(User.class, id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that i'm late but i will answer your question:

the date must have this format:

```
'2000-01-01 00:00:00'
```

**yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss**

and the `type` of 'mydate' must be `"java.sql.Date"` instead of `"java.util.Date"`